# QlikView Script Count Conditional Occurrences

Tags: count, qlikview

I have a data set that shows engineer visits and the type of job attended.

Engineer's Visit Table:

```
OrderNum, Engineer, Job Type, Date  
1         John      Install   01/04/15  
2         Phil      Remove    02/04/15
3         George    Install   01/04/15
4         George    Replace   02/04/15
5         George    Replace   03/04/15
6         John      Install   01/04/15
7         John      Install   01/04/15
8         John      Replace   02/04/15
9         John      Remove    02/04/15
```

For the example table above - I would like to show for each engineer (but using John as an example):

- His predominant job type was "Install";
- The total number of jobs he attended was 5;
- He worked for 3 days;
- Meaning he attended 1.67 jobs per day.

I was attempting to add this to the load script using various additional columns but I'm having trouble getting an aggr/count statement to work.

Is this a reasonable approach or am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to do it in the script because then you would have to try and guess any combination of selections your users might make before hand and create aggregations for each case. In the front end it is fairly trivial except for the 1st measure. To illustrate the problem I added 2 more orders for Phil an Install and a Replace so that he has 1 of each

Here is the first draft I made:
[image]

Now the problem is that '-' for Phil. The mode() function is working as designed there but I bet nobody wants to see that the job they perform most often is nothing.

I tried a few things but this is as close as I got to something useful:

[image]

The expression I used is

```
  `if(isnull(mode([Job Type])),concat(DISTINCT [Job Type],','),mode([Job Type]))`
```

but it also isn't as good as it could be (now the guys with no clear mode just get a list of all the jobs they've done, rather than a list of the joint most often done jobs. But at least now it looks like they are working). I am however stumped as to how to get it to do what I want

Comment: I had tried creating expressions and was able to get the total number completed and the ratio but I was stumped on the most performed job.  Your expression should work for me.  In my scenario - each engineer could be assigned a typical job type (eg - John would normally do installs) and the engineers name specifies his normal job type - eg "(Installer) John". I could amend my load script to show the normal job type.  Not 100% sure how to reflect that in the expression though.  Otherwise - I could maybe return the MAX for that engineer instead of your concat.

Comment: PS - I'll mark this as the answer as it's done what I needed. I'll have a play around with the default job type.

Comment: The concat is only there for a a guy has two jobs occurring equally. Sounds like that isn't likely in your case

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it was likely in my case due to the volume of jobs we're looking at and the fact that engineers should mostly work on their job type... but looking at the result, there is a handful of engineers with equal numbers of job types.  Thanks for your help.